# How can I query records that have a created date older than 1 hour

Tags: apex, soql

I'm using the following query to retrieve Case records that are older than 1 hour:

```
DateTime dt = System.Now().addHours(1);
            
String query =  'SELECT Id, Status, CreatedDate ' +
                        'FROM Case ' +
                        'WHERE CreatedDate > :dt';
```

My query does not seem to be returning anything at all.

Answer (score 3):

I think the date initialization and the conditions are a little bit different,

If we debug the times we could find that

```
System.Now()                =  2022-07-15 05:56:32
System.Now().addHours(1)    =  2022-07-15 06:56:32
System.Now().addHours(-1)   =  2022-07-15 04:56:32
```

So if we want older than one hour, we need thee records that were created one hour ago or more.

```
One hour ago is:
System.Now().addHours(-1)   =  2022-07-15 04:56:32
```

And the condition is older than,
if we use

CreatedDate >  = expects that the CreatedDate is after the one given

CreatedDate <  = expects that the CreatedDate is before the one given

So I think this could work.

```
DateTime dt = System.Now().addHours(-1);
            
String query =  'SELECT Id, Status, CreatedDate ' +
                        'FROM Case ' +
                        'WHERE CreatedDate < :dt';
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this

```
Select Id,casenumber,LastModifiedDate From case  Where HOUR_IN_DAY(LastModifiedDate) >1
```

Above will give you the list of case whose created date is more than 1 hour.

And to fetch created records in past one hour only, try below :-

```
Select Id,casenumber,LastModifiedDate From case  Where LastModifiedDate = TODAY AND HOUR_IN_DAY(LastModifiedDate) >1
```

Comment: Priya - Is not this query considering LastModifiedDate greater than 1AM by any chance?

Comment: @JefersonChaves That's how I'm reading it. I've downvoted this answer because it doesn't appear to solve the question being asked here.